# How to eliminate [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mpg.csv' in Python?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am trying to import mpg dataset in Jupyter notebook. Here is my code:

```
import csv
%precision 2
with open('mpg.csv') as csvfile:
    mpg = list(csv.DictReader(csvfile))
```

I am getting the error, saying: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mpg.csv'

Can anyone point out what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is your jupyter notebook is not running in the same folder where your mpg.csv file is present. Technically, your present working directory is different.

To solve this try to add the full path of your csv file like this-

path = 'D:/xyx/xyz/.../mpg.csv'

and then pass this path in the open function. I hope this should work.

good  luck ~~

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I figured out the issue. My csv file was not in the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

jupyter online by default looking for your file in their own directory not in your local directories so first upload that file into jupyter
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should fix the problem:

```py
with open('datasets/mpg.csv') as csvfile:
```